# No errors inside shader Java OpenGL code, but nothing is rendered inside window

Tags: java, opengl, jogl

I am trying to find what am I doing wrong in my code. I am using JOGL.

I'd like to make two VBOs, one for vertices, other for indices, inside a given object.

There is no error inside `init(GLAutoDrawable glAutoDrawable)` function, but `display(GLAutoDrawable glAutoDrawable)` does not show my object when running the program.

Where am I making a mistake? Thank you for help.

My code:

```
public class Test1 implements GLEventListener {

    private int program;

    IntBuffer vao = IntBuffer.allocate(1);
    private IntBuffer buffers = IntBuffer.allocate(2);
    private float[] vertices = {
            -0.853250f, -0.136293f, -0.188932f,
             -0.129650f, 0.416492f, 0.336788f,
             -1.129635f, 0.416492f, 0.661708f,
             -1.747674f, 0.416492f, -0.188932f,
             -1.129635f, 0.416492f, -1.039572f,
             -0.129650f, 0.416492f, -0.714652f,
             -0.576865f, 1.310922f, 0.661708f,
             -1.576849f, 1.310922f, 0.336788f,
             -1.576849f, 1.310922f, -0.714652f,
             -0.576865f, 1.310922f, -1.039572f,
             0.041175f, 1.310922f, -0.188932f,
             -0.853250f, 1.863707f, -0.188932f
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a considerable number of things wrong.

- Your Vertex Shader is very clearly the code for a Fragment Shader. I don't know where you copied it from, but you need to fix that.
- `gluPerspective` is intended for use with the Fixed-Function-Pipeline. It has no effect when you're using programmable shaders. You need to put a uniform for a projection matrix in your vertex shader and manually pass that matrix to the GL.
- Most Java Wrappers for OpenGL require that their Buffers be "Directly Allocated", which means the backing memory is natively allocated, as opposed to being Java-Allocated. The easiest way to do that is with `ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(sizeInBytes);`, which returns a `ByteBuffer` that can then be converted to an `IntBuffer` or `FloatBuffer` using `asFloatBuffer` and `asIntBuffer`.

Comment: You can use com.jogamp.common.nio.Buffers.newDirectIntBuffer(int) to create direct NIO buffers for JOGL and "new GLU()" should be replaced by "GLU.createGLU(gl)". Excellent reply by the way, it deserves an upvote :)